# Confused on this logic-Dracket

Tags: scheme, logic, racket

```scm
(define (incbyD x D)
  (if (< x 10)
      (modulo (+ D x) 10)
      (+ (* 10 (incbyD (round (/ x 10)) D))
         (modulo (+ D x) 10))))
```

---

Test cases;
// This game me the right output, because it incremented each value by 4

```
(incbyD 1234 4) 
; ==> 5678
```

Wrong output, it should been  0856

```
(incbyD 7523 3)
; ==> 1856
```

Wrong output , 87695

```
(incbyD 54362 3)
; ==> 87795
```

I though the logic was right, but apparently it seem to be not working all the time. The issue I see is that the carry value is getting displayed.

Comment: What is incybD supposed to do?

Comment: D is the desire value that you want to increment by. For example, if the x = 1234 D= 2. Output should be 2456

Comment: increment WHAT by? 1234 + 2 = 1236. Incrementing the digits by 2 gives 3456. You have to describe what the function is supposed to do accurately or it'll be hard for people to help. If it's incrementing the digits, describe exactly what is supposed to happen when there is a carry value.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `round` with `floor`. Or, more clearly, replace `(round (/ x 10))` with `(quotient x 10)`.